# Bug with strlen?

Tags: c, string, ubuntu, gcc

I'm just getting started with C and I just started trying to figure out
call by reference in functions. I have noticed an odd result in my output
when using strlen() to iterate over a string and modify its contents. In this
example the result of strlen() is 3, not including the null character,
but if I do not explicitly check for the null character (or use less than the
result of strlen() instead of less than or equals) during the for loop then
it gives a bizarre bit character in the output which I ASSUME is because of the null character?

Please help this noob to understand what is happening here.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f_test_s(char s[]);
void f_test_s2(char s[]);

int main(){
    char s_test[] = "abc";

    f_test_s(s_test);
    f_test_s2(s_test);

    puts("\nTest complete!");

    return 0;
}


void f_test_s(char s[]){

    puts("Test #1: ");
    printf("string before: %s\n", s);

    int len = strlen(s);
    printf("strlen() = %d\n", len); 
    int i=0;             
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++){
        if(s[i] != '\0'){
            s[i]++;
        }
    }

    printf("string after: %s\n", s);

}


void f_test_s2(char s[]){

    puts("\nTest #2: ");
    printf("string before: %s\n", s);

    int len = strlen(s);
    printf("strlen() = %d\n", len);
    int i=0;         
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++){
        s[i]++;
    }

    printf("string after: %s\n", s);

}
```

output:

```
Test #1: 
string before: abc
strlen() = 3
string after: bcd

Test #2: 
string before: bcd
strlen() = 3
string after: cde

Test complete!
```

If it matters I am using gcc version 7.3.0 on Ubuntu. I am definitely
not an expert with either C, gcc, or Ubuntu.

Comment: The length returned by `strlen` does not include the terminating `'\0'`. Therefore you either need to loop while `i < len`, or while `s[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: You are however free to assume that the null terminator is always located at `s[strlen(s)]`.

Comment: A good rule of bug discovery:  if you think you've found a bug in a simple library function such as `strlen()` on a widely-used platform such as Ubuntu, walk away from the computer, clear your mind, come back, and then start looking through **your** code for the bug.  After you've done that about 100 times, **then** you can safely start to think, "**Maybe** there's a bug in this function used billions and billions of times by others, and I'm the first to find it."  Yes, bugs in widely-used library code happen, but you almost certainly aren't the one finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
```

to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

since [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) returns the length of the string. A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (**without including the terminating null character itself**).

Your code invokes Undefined Behavior (UB), since you go out of bounds. Standard string functions (like `printf()`) depend on the NULL terminating character to mark the end of the string. Without it, they do not know when to stop . . .

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks! I was thinking for some reason that strlen() = 3 would cause the loop to increment 3 times, without appreciating that the fact that it starts at 0 meant that it would iterate 4 times. I am dumb! Problem solved.

Comment: No you are not, you are just getting started, like we all did at some time @some_guy632. Glad that your problem was solved, and more importantly, that you understood. Also, let me welcome you in Stackoverflow and congratulate you for posting a good first question (that's why I upvoted it), with an MCVE! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    s[i]++;
}
```

It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    s[i]++;
}
```

`s[len]` is the null char (0).  When you removed null char and replaced it with the value of 1, the contents of the array are now `{'a', 'b', 'c', 0x1}`.  And when printf attempts to print `s` it's going to keep printing characters past the value memory address of the array until it encounters a null char.  Technically this is undefined behavior.

Comment: But why? If strlen() = 3 and the array has 4 elements including the null character then why does it have to be less than instead of less than or equal to? Am I misunderstanding how arrays work in C?

Comment: @some_guy632 because arrays in `C` start at 0 and thus s[3] would be the fourth element which is `\0`

Comment: If `s` is `"abc"`, then strlen("abc") is 3.   `s[0]` is `'a'`. `s[1]` is `'b'`. `s[2]` is `'c'`.  And `s[3]` is the null char.

Comment: @some_guy632 You are correct that the array has 4 elements, but in the 4th iteration of you loop, you increment the null terminator so that the array is no longer a string. (eg, you've changed the null-terminator to a non-zero value)